# Finding the Jordan Canonical Form of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let $J_5$ be the $5x5$ Jordan block, with eigenvalue zero, and define $B=J^2$. Find the Jordan form of $B$.

I found that the $J_5$ is a matrix with $0s$ on the diagonal and $1s$ on top. I squared it and tried to find the Jordan canonical form.

However, is there an easier way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that the kernel (nullspace) of $B$ has dimension $2$, so $B$ contains two Jordan blocks.

Note that since $J^5 = 0$ but $J^4 \neq 0$, we have $B^3 = 0$ but $B^2 \neq 0$.  Conclude that the largest Jordan block of $B$ has size $3$.

Conclude that $B$ has Jordan form $J_3 \oplus J_2$.

Comment: I am having a doubt; How did you get $\ker B$ has $\dim =2$

Comment: Suppose that $Bx=0\implies J^2(x)=0\implies?$

Comment: Do you mean to say that $x,Jx$ will be a basis of $\ker B$?Is so why?

Comment: @learnmore $J^2$ is in reduced row echelon form.  Its rank is clearly $3$.

Comment: Can you please do the problem in some more detail.I don't get it